# MS Access SQL - Table Query Distinct Lines into One

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing a query on table to take multiple lines that share multiple pieces of information and form them into one line. The only differences between these lines is several columuns that are `Y` or `N`. I would like the ones that have `Y` to override those have have `N` and if there are no `Y`, then `N` should be seen.

An example of my current table

```
col 1           col 2           col 3          col 4
AZ99ZB102       8               Y              N
AZ99ZB102       8               Y              Y
AZ99ZB201       4               N              N
AZ99ZB201       4               Y              N
```

Expected Result:

```
col 1           col 2           col 3          col 4
AZ99ZB102       8               Y              Y
AZ99ZB201       4               Y              N
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with basic aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from table
group by col1, col2;
```

I took the liberty of renaming the columns to be "col" rather than "row".  The latter seems totally confusing.